# Magento 2.1.7 - Problem on Readiness Check on "Check Cron Scripts"

Tags: magento-2.1, cron, readiness-check

I have a Client with **Magento 2.1.7**, I need to success the **Readiness Check** so I can install extensions or upgrade Magento version...

All the checks are ok! It says to:

**"Your PHP version is correct (7.0.33)"**

but the **Check Cron Scripts** failed.

```
Error from Updater Application Cron Script:
Found non-writable path(s):
/var/www/vhosts/gevi/httpdocs/php.ini.sample
```

The file does even exist, and if I create it with permission 755 the problem is the same...

I think the problem is on CRON failing, in details:

When I run **"php bin/magento setup:cron:run"** to execute the CRON I got an error on the log:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/vhosts/gevi/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php on line 72
```

Seems that php code is incorrect? Incompatible between Magento version and PHP version? But it says version 7.0 is ok!

HELP!

[image: error]

Comment: can you share screenshot of error to get better idea about the error?

Comment: added! the problem is that the cron wont run?

Comment: can you tell me which commands are you using for changing php version?

Comment: im not changing php version, its 7.0.33 right now

Comment: you must have changed it before right? i'm saying this because it could be the reason for your error

Comment: Ok, i changed it through PLESK

Comment: check with `php -v` command to know which php version are you using?

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: php -v return 7.0.33

Comment: no, the problem remain, when I run the cron with php it returns the same error on that line

Comment: seems that php /var/www/vhosts/gemavip.com/httpdocs/bin/magento cron:run give the error in the screenshot, otherwise the php bin/magento setup:cron:run its ok
 - the error is the same: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/vhosts/gema/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php on line 72

Comment: you don't have to run `cron` command if you're installing magento, you can just re-run the setup in browser.

Comment: im not installing magento, i need to install an extension, but the readiness check fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Just create Magento folder in your `app/design/frontend` and `app/design/adminhtml`, Most of the time it should solve the problem.**

```
 cd <magento_root>
 find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} +
 find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} +
 chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**Use this commands:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: I already have a Magento folder in  app/design/frontend, I have to set some particular permission?

Can you explain "can be solved by using root making www-data the owner and giving 775 to folders and files" are you referring to Magento folder?
Thanks!

Comment: please check updated answer

Comment: "Operation not permitted", i'm in SSH through putty with the user of this subdomain but seems not root, can I operate via PLESK?

Comment: using su -root I dont have root password and on PLESK seems not present root user (only admin) but via SSH su -admin says "admin not exist" :(

Comment: any solution? :(

Comment: did you check the loaded configuration file using `phpinfo()` as shown in this link 

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html**

Comment: Im losting the point :D the point is that on readiness check it says that php version is ok, but it fails "Check Cron Scripts" cause a permission on a file that dont exist, im only deducing depends on fail when i run "php bin/magento setup:cron:run"

Comment: Seems that I cant access SSH root with my hosting, so I cant apply the solutions belove... any other way to install an extensions if cant resolve Readiness Check?
The module is in app/code folder but without Readiness Check I cant activate it

Comment: why don't you just create a folder `app/code` and paste your module there?

Comment: Done but without Readiness Check I cant activate it

Comment: just upgrade and deploy then `cache:flush`

Comment: so I have to put inside app/code the module, then can you please write me the command for upgrade and deploy? Im worried about this command because the site is online

Comment: i've updated an answer

Comment: OK... php bin/magento setup:upgrade... are you sure this command cant crash anything? can I prevent or rollback?

Comment: if you want to install module in your magento you have to do `upgrade`, `deploy` commands for more info please refer this link 

**https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/install-magento-2-extension-by-composer/**

Comment: OK i make a backup and run, thanks I let you know!

Comment: seems go ok but now site goes down with ad error 500... can I investigate if is the new extension?

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Mageplaza_Smtp data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.1

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Mageplaza_Smtp data: current version - none, required version - 1.1.1

Comment: OK I have updated on database the record "data_version" that was null on table "setup_module", now the error 500 disappear and the extensions is ok but when I click on it 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Object DOMDocument should be created.  I think the problem is the exception not ok?

Comment: it could be your module exception

Comment: unfurtunatly now all backend admin, all the sections, return this error: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Object DOMDocument should be created.

Comment: I open a new question, for the moment I have not resolved the Readiness Check but now I have to resolve the extensions error, thanks!

Comment: you can mark it as accept and upvote the answer if it's solved your issue related to the question most possible way. :)